# A way to prevent non-throwing-exceptions code from executing without putting both throwing and non-throwing code in one try block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In my program, I have an inner listener class. Its purpose is to open a file and read data from it:

```
// This declaration is outside of the inner class.
SimulationModel model;
// End of declarations.

class OpenListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
        fileOpen.showOpenDialog(gui);
        if (fileOpen.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileOpen.getSelectedFile());
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
                Object modelObject;
                modelObject = ois.readObject();
                model = (SimulationModel) modelObject;
                consolePanel.printToConsole("File opened.\n\n");                

                // Do stuff with model object of SimulationModel class.
                // About 10 lines of code, mostly reading from model.
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                consolePanel.printToConsole("Error during file opening.\n\n");
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Lines of code I have commented out (// Do stuff (...)) do not throw any exceptions, but if the file was not read correctly, these lines should not be executed. That is why I have put both I/O code and commented-out-code in the try block. However, I have doubts about placing code that does not throw any exceptions in the try block.

Would be there a more elegant way to ensure that commented-out-code will not execute, but exceptions are checked only in code performing I/O operations?

Comment: Does the language require a catch?  It maybe better to have an structure similar to the HTML DOM that you can traverse the errors or index them directly.

Comment: @VSH - Java doesn't work that way. A method must either catch checked exceptions or declare that it throws them. Allowing exceptions to reach the framework code will generally result in bad things. The Swing framework (which OP seems to be using) defines a contract for `actionPerformed` that does not allow thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would segregate the code that reads the file in a separate method. It can print a message and return `null` if there is an error:

```
class OpenListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
        fileOpen.showOpenDialog(gui);
        if (fileOpen.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            model = readModel(fileOpen.getSelectedFile());
            if (model != null) {
                // Do stuff with model object of SimulationModel class.
            }
        }           
    }

    private static SimulationModel readModel(File file) {
        SimulationModel modelObject = null;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
        {
            modelObject = (SimulationModel) ois.readObject();
            consolePanel.printToConsole("File opened.\n\n");                
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            consolePanel.printToConsole("Error during file opening.\n\n");
        }
        return modelObject;
    }
}
```

You might want to consider more robust error handling than simply logging the error to the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that is precisely what I was looking for.

Considering error handling, if there is an error, user will simply fail opening the file he chose and the program will continue working, e.g. another file can be chosen for opening.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the contents of the try-catch block into a method call. Also, it greatly depends on how your program can proceed upon a raised Exception. can it still go on? If not a simple printToConsole might not be the proper reaction.